# Launching an activity from an AppWidget

Tags: android

How do i launch an activity from an AppWidget? I want to give the user the ability to edit its settings.

Answer (score 0):

All the AppWidget methods have a Context: you can use that to create an Intent to launch your Activity.

EDIT: strictly speaking, you don't even need the Context (just create an Intent and then call `startActivity`).

Answer (score 0):

you can find a lot of examples around the internet  this example is excellent courtesy of Mark Murphy

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainWidgetActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
// to the button
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget);
rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
```

while MainWidgetActivity.class is the Activity you want to launch