# Android Widgets w/ AdapterViewFlipper - Pending Intent Template does not get filled in with extras

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am making an Android homescreen widget populated with content from the net. Getting it setup I was referencing the StackWidget example from google's pages, and some other [questions regarding the setOnClickFillInIntent() function being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828747/start-mainactivity-from-appwidget-doesnt-work). Despite that, I cannot find out why that the click intent fires without the template getting populated with the filled-in extras.  The extras aren't null. The widget loads and displays content perfectly fine, but it will crash with a NullPointerEx if clicked.

Something I've noticed is that if the click ID `widget_capsule_content` in the item layout is at the root level (the LinearLayout) of the layout, the intent does not fire at all.  It does fire if it is in its child (the FrameLayout), but the extras get left off.

**Layout for widget_capsule.xml - the individual collection items:** - none of these examples are elegant yet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="@drawable/capsule_bg5">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget_capsule_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_thumbnail"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/capsule_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="@color/white_text"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:text="title"/>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Layout for the widget_layout.xml, the collection holder:**

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white_text"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <AdapterViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/widget_flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:flipInterval="10000"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_loading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_loading"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Relevant Code from the WidgetReceiver** (extends AppWidgetProvider):

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager wManager, int[] appWidgetIds){
    //This method is allowed to handle multiple widgets VIA appWidgetId.
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            IHWidgetReceiver.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = wManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        //service intent
        Intent sIntent = new Intent(context, IHWidgetService.class);
        sIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
        sIntent.setData(Uri.parse(sIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_flipper, sIntent);

        // The empty view is displayed when the collection has no items. It should be a sibling
        // of the collection view.
        remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.widget_flipper, R.id.widget_loading);

        //Pending Intent to prepare individual item clicks
        /*Class<? extends  Activity> startA = IntentUtil.getActivityClass(context, IHDetail.class);
        Intent pI = new Intent(context, startA); //3
        pI.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pI.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
        pI.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  //3
        pI.setData(Uri.parse(pI.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_flipper,
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, pI, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));*/

        //For sake of breakpointing below, this block is made to match the StackViewWidget sample as much as possible.
        //It suffers the same issue as the activity launch behavior above
        Intent pI = new Intent(context, IHWidgetReceiver.class);
        pI.setAction(ACTION_CLICK);
        pI.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
        pI.setData(Uri.parse(pI.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_flipper,
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, pI, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));


        //done
        Log.i("Widget", "Widget Updated");
        wManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        wManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(allWidgetIds, widgetId);

    }
    super.onUpdate(context, wManager, appWidgetIds);
} 

@Override
public void onReceive(Context rContext, Intent rIntent) {
    Ln.e("RECEIVED THING + ");
    AppWidgetManager wManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(rContext);
    if (rIntent.getAction().equals(ACTION_CLICK)) {

        Toast.makeText(rContext, "Touched view ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Bundle eBundle = rIntent.getExtras();
            CmsContent content = (CmsContent) eBundle.getSerializable(IHConstants.MS_CONTENT_EXTRA);
            String id = eBundle.getString(IHConstants.MS_ID_EXTRA);
            //trying again without the bundle
            CmsContent content2 = (CmsContent)  rIntent.getSerializableExtra(IHConstants.MS_CONTENT_EXTRA);
            String id2 = rIntent.getStringExtra(IHConstants.MS_ID_EXTRA);
            //breakpointed here. all of the above extras are null. the next line is a NPE

             Intent activityIntent = IntentUtil.getDetailIntent(rContext, content2, id2);
            activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            rContext.startActivity(activityIntent);
    }
    super.onReceive(rContext, rIntent);
}
```

**Relevant Code from the WidgetViewsFactory** (implementing RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory ):

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    //populate view w/ data
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_capsule);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.capsule_title, getContent(position).getShortTitle());
    rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_thumbnail, getContent(position).getThumbnail());

    //intent junk
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    Intent act = new Intent();
    //act.putExtra(IHConstants.MS_ID_EXTRA, capsules.get(position).getId());
    //act.putExtra(IHConstants.MS_CONTENT_EXTRA, getContent(position));
    extras.putString(IHConstants.MS_ID_EXTRA, capsules.get(position).getId());
    extras.putSerializable(IHConstants.MS_CONTENT_EXTRA, getContent(position));
    act.putExtras(extras);

    Ln.e("content in extras " + capsules.get(position).getId() + " | " + getContent(position).getDetailSection());  
    //Log indicates that the extras were not null when inserted
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_capsule_content, act);
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: Try to remove clickable and focusable  attributes from widget_capsule.xml.
In my case it works for a single ImageView wrapped into RelativeLayout.
Having a root Layout seems crucial for AdapterViewFlipper to pass click intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by removing the extra in the pending intent template. Putting that extra there in the Template blew away the bundle of extras set by the adapter.

```
//pI.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId); 
remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_flipper,
                 PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, pI, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Only place extras in the bundle set with setOnClickFillInIntent().